# Create different headers in python docx

Tags: python, header, python-docx

A report is being written with docx python, however when trying to generate different headers by implementing different sections, it does mantain the same unique header. It was also tried to create a FIRST_PAGE_HEADER but with no success.

Some orientation about how to create different headers for different pages would be very appreciated. Thanks in advance

This is the code that is working for creating one header, but not 2 or more for the different sections of the report

```
#code

doc= docx.Document()

doc.add_section()


section = doc.sections[0]
header = section.header
paragraph = header.paragraphs[0]
paragraph.text = "Text on the left\t"
   
paragraph.style = doc.styles["Header"]
```

and this had been tryed from the documentation

```
new_section = document.add_section(WD_SECTION.ODD_PAGE)
new_section.start_type
```

Comment: Show the simplest code that doesn't behave as you expect. In this example you do not add a second section. Get rid of all the paragraph settings and table and just set text of one to "foo" and the other to "bar" to keep things simple.

Comment: @scanny, done, just a simple header is now there but i don´t know how to include a second section. I tried the second part of the code and after a new header but it did not work.

Comment: I'm only seeing one section in that code. Create a single block of code that uses both sections and headers and state what behavior it has that you don't expect. Don't ask the reader to guess what the code would look like or what the behavior you're seeing is. If you add a second section, show adding a second section and manipulating its header.

Answer (score 0):

My recomendation would be to configure a word document with these different headers and save it as template. Then open the template and add info in it. It solved my problems with adding page numeration and the metioned problem with different headers as well.